# Java to only split at first occurrence of "="

Tags: java, regex

Trying to split the input as mentioned in the example below

It works for, e.g.:

```
"Data Structures=Coding,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";
```

But not for:

```
"Data Structures=Cod=ing,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";
```

I want to ignore the second `=` in the word coding and everything after it, how can we do that? Can we use regex? Guava splitter limit?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // This String contains key-value pairs.
    String value
        = "Data Structures=Coding,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";

    Map<String, String>
        mp
        = Splitter.on(',')
              .withKeyValueSeparator('=')
              .split(value);
```

Comment: How do you know which '=' to split on?

Comment: After a more careful read, the OP wants to ignore the second `=` and everything after it and before the next comma

Comment: It should always spilt at the first "=", @JuanMendes yes you are correct, I want to ignore the second = and everything after it and before the next comma

Comment: @JoakimDanielson would you be able to rewrite just that bit of code if possible? I have tried that already but doesn't seem to work. I am able to limit"," which I dont want to do. I want to limit the "="

Comment: Split on commas First. Split each resulting string on the first equals.

Answer (score 0):

From question:

> I want to ignore the second "=" in the word coding **and everything after it**

To eliminate the second `=` and everything after, use:

```java
replaceAll("(=[^=,]*)=[^,]*", "$1")
```

*Test*

```java
String value = "Data Structures=Cod=ing,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";

Map<String, String> mp = Splitter.on(',')
        .withKeyValueSeparator('=')
        .split(value.replaceAll("(=[^=,]*)=[^,]*", "$1"));

System.out.println(mp);
```

*Output*

```
{Data Structures=Cod, Sports=Football, Capital=Delhi}
```

---

From comment:

> I wanted to have the data after the second "=" and just eliminate the second "="

With Java 9+ it can be done like this:

```java
String value = "Data Structures=Cod=in=g,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";

Map<String, String> mp = Splitter.on(',')
        .withKeyValueSeparator('=')
        .split(Pattern.compile("(=[^=,]*)=([^,]*)").matcher(value)
                      .replaceAll(m -> m.group(1) + m.group(2).replace("=", "")));

System.out.println(mp);
```

*Output*

```
{Data Structures=Coding, Sports=Football, Capital=Delhi}
```

Comment: This works, what if I wanted to have the data after the second "=" is that possible and just eliminating the second "="

Comment: Data Structures=Cod-2-YTD, Sports=Foot-ball, Capital=Del=hi Expected O/P : Data Structures=Cod-2-YTD, Sports=Foot-ball, Capital=Delhi is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to achieve what you want. A simple way is to use `String#substring` to get the required substrings for the key and the value of the required `Map`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Data Structures=Cod=ing,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";
        
        Map<String, String> map = 
                Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
                .filter(s -> s.indexOf('=') != -1)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf('=')), 
                            s -> s.substring(s.indexOf('=') + 1)
                        )
                );
        
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Data Structures=Cod=ing, Capital=Delhi, Sports=Football}
```

If you want to eliminate the second `=`, you can replace it with `""` as shown below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Data Structures=Cod=ing,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";

        Map<String, String> map = 
                Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
                .filter(s -> s.indexOf('=') != -1)
                .collect(Collectors
                        .toMap(s -> 
                            s.substring(0, s.indexOf('=')), 
                            s -> s.substring(s.indexOf('=') + 1).replace("=", "")
                        )
                );

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Data Structures=Coding, Capital=Delhi, Sports=Football}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Guava, but standard Java `split()` method has an (often overseen) second parameter that limits the results size or better, how often the delimiter is searched for:

```
String value = "Data Structures=Cod=ing,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";
Map<String, String> mp = 
    Pattern.compile(",")
    .splitAsStream(value)
    .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
```

To ignore all but the first equal, that is, remove all equal signs from the value part, just add a replace like:

```
String value = "Data Structures=Cod=ing,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi";
Map<String, String> mp = 
    Pattern.compile(",")
    .splitAsStream(value)
    .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1].replace("=","")));
```

This will throw an Exception if any entry (string between commas) does not have an equal sign. To avoid that, add a filter to the stream:

```
String value = "Data Structures=Cod=ing,Sports=Football,Capital=Delhi,Error";
Map<String, String> mp = 
    Pattern.compile(",")
    .splitAsStream(value)
    .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
    .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1].replace("=","")));
```